# How to configure messages.properties in spring bean annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am starting a new project with spring 4 and I am confusing how I can map my i18n file: messages.properties..

In spring 3 I was using xml configuration like this:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="messages" />
</bean>
<bean id="i18n" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/..../messages.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And in my jsps files I access it by:

```
<spring:message code="any key" />
```

In spring 4 I am avoiding to use xml configuration.. I tried the following:

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() throws Exception {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("message.properties");
    return resourceBundleMessageSource;
}

@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("messages.properties");
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(resource);
    return propertiesFactoryBean;
}
```

That class is annotated with @Configuration, but apparently is missing anything..

When I try to access index.jsp, I receive the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'application.title' for locale 'pt_BR'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is it your file on classpath at deploy folder?

Comment: yes, but the file is loaded successfully, the problem happens in the jsp file, apparently the tag <spring:message ... /> do not found the mapped keys @jcrada

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<spring:message code="myMessage"/> with <fmt:message key="myMessage"/>
```

and on web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>messages</param-value>
</context-param>
```

dont forget to add fmt taglib

Comment: I need to load it by spring, because in some controllers I use it too:  @Inject private MessageSource messageSource..

Comment: did you try place files under resources/i18n folder? <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />

Comment: It is in resources/messages.properties, and I'm trying load it so: resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages.properties");

Answer (score 0):

You need to put file name for each local language. In your case you need

```
messages_BR.properties or messages_pt_BR.properties
```

And all the messages in those files.